# FileReader read line by line

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, filereader

I just want to read a Textfile, which is on the Desktop and in *.CSV, line by line, and put each line in a String List or similar. I found a few approaches but it's not solved in a gently way. It's a lot of bad code.

Ideas? or good Codesnippets for me?

Comment: What about public static string[] ReadAllLines(string path) ?

Comment: *Don't reinvent the wheel.* Use any CSV parser. For example [this one](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper). And this is not the way to ask good question *good Codesnippets for me?* You need to show what you tried.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: The problem is I have no expirience in using this CSV-Parser with Visual Studio. I'm sorry about to beeing not a pro.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(pathToCSV)
```

Better yet, use the built-in .NET Framework type for parsing CSV files:

`TextFieldParser`, a hidden gem many do not know about since it's been strangely exiled to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly:

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\file.csv")
   MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
   MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
   Dim currentRow As String()
   While Not MyReader.EndOfData
      currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
   End While 
End Using
```

Sample code taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Question is tagged in `VB.net` you are posting a c# code, please convert the code and post

Comment: @NeethuSoman, oops :) posted a VB.NET sample.

Comment: Nice so i remove down vote, have a nice time

Answer (score 0):

The quick and simple approach, use [`File.ReadAllLines(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)(or `File.ReadLines`) to read all into memory and create a `String()`.  Then loop all lines and use `String.Split(","c)` to create a `String()` for every line's fields, so like this:

```
Dim lineFields As New List(Of String())
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("CsvFileName.Csv")
    Dim fields = line.Split(","c)
    lineFields.Add(fields)
Next
```

The more reliable approach: use an available CSV parser that also handles edge cases like `"A","B,C","B"`. The only available in the .NET framework is the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) ([here'](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)s another).

Here's an example:

```
Dim lineFields As New List(Of String())
Using parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\CsvFileName.csv")
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} ' fields are separated by comma
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True ' each of the values is enclosed with double quotes
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
    Dim line As String = parser.ReadLine()
    lineFields.Add(parser.ReadFields())
    Dim fields() As String = parser.ReadFields()
    While fields IsNot Nothing
        lineFields.Add(fields)
        fields = parser.ReadFields()
    End While
End Using
```

---

Finally, here's what you've originally requested, a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.90)) approach:

```
Dim lineFields As New List(Of String())
Using fileStream = File.OpenRead("CsvFileName.Csv")
    Using streamReader = New StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, True)
        Dim line As String = streamReader.ReadLine()
        While line IsNot Nothing
            Dim fields As String() = line.Split(","c)
            lineFields.Add(fields)
            line = streamReader.ReadLine()
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `"D:\me.csv"` be the input file then the following code will help you to store each line as a string in `stringList`

```
    Dim txtReader As IO.TextReader = New IO.StreamReader("D:\me.csv")
    Dim stringList As New List(Of String)
    Dim str As String = ""
    While True
        If str Is Nothing Then
            Exit While
       Else
            str = txtReader.ReadLine
            stringList.Add(str)
       End IF
    End While
```

**input file :**

```
Title1,Title2,Title3
one,two,three
example1,example2,example3
```

**output stringList:**

```
stringList(0) : Title1,Title2,Title3
stringList(1) : one,two,three
stringList(2) : example1,example2,example3
```